# Advice on mixing legacy ASP site with .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, com, asp-classic, e-commerce, paypal

We've just been tasked with updating an e-commerce application to use PayPal's PayFlow product.  The site was originally written in classic ASP except for the credit card processing portion which was a COM component.

Our plan is to replace the COM component with a .NET 2.0 component.  I'm looking for tips, gotcha, etc. before we embark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Dan Bartels' blog post about 
[Replacing Old Classic ASP COM Componenets With .NET Assemblies](http://blog.danbartels.com/articles/322.aspx)  is the right starting point for you.

Implementing the details described in the blog post, you should be able to instantiate your objects in classic asp and execute code like this:

```
Dim myObject
Set myObject = Server.CreateObject("MyWebDLL.MyClass")
Response.Write myObject.MyMethod("test")
```